# Pyspark Dataframe join is giving erratic results

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

`df_1` is below -

```
+------+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----------+
|period|col1 |col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|col9|amount    |
+------+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----------+
|202302|20110|b925|0000|tcp |us  |null|8200|acpy|na  |-1        |
|202302|20110|b925|0000|tcp |us  |null|0000|acpy|na  |8         |
|202302|20110|b925|3051|tcp |us  |ds  |7588|acpy|na  |1256508.18|
+------+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----------+
```

`df_2` is below -

```
+-----+----+----+------+----+----+----+----+----+-----------+---+---+
|col1 |col2|col3|period|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|amount     |p1 |p2 |
+-----+----+----+------+----+----+----+----+----+-----------+---+---+
|20110|b925|3051|202302|tcp |ds  |us  |na  |acpy|-1396325.95|1  |0  |
|20110|b925|0000|202302|tcp |null|us  |na  |acpy|-16587.17  |1  |0  |
+-----+----+----+------+----+----+----+----+----+-----------+---+---+
```

Code I've used to join above two dataframes -

```
df = df_2.join(df_1
               , on = (
                            (df_2["col3"] == df_1["col3"]) 
                          & (df_2["col1"] == df_1["col1"]) 
                          & (df_2["col2"] == df_1["col2"])
                          & (df_2["period"] == df_1["period"])
                        ) 
               , how = 'left').select(
                                df_2["col1"],
                                df_2["col2"], 
                                df_2["col3"], 
                                df_1["col7"], 
                                coalesce(df_1["amount"], lit(0)).alias("amount")
                                )
df.show(truncate=False)

+-----+----+----+----+----------+
|col1 |col2|col3|col7|amount    |
+-----+----+----+----+----------+
|20110|b925|3051|7588|1256508.18|
|20110|b925|0000|0000|8         |
|20110|b925|0000|8200|-1        |
+-----+----+----+----+----------+
```

this is the result I'm getting and it is skipping the rows for `df_2["amount"] = -16587.17` and `df_2["amount"] = -1396325.95`
which ideally should bring 0 in the result set as i have done a left join but it is not doing that. I even tried achieving same using `full` join but no luck.

Please help.

Comment: it isn't wrong given you're selecting `amount` from `df1`, not `df2`.

Comment: is there a way to bring 0 instead for those rows?

Comment: what is your intended output? if you're joining the rows, it correctly merged the two dataframes - and you would have to select `df2.amount` to understand the join.

Comment: yes i need all the rows from `df_2` but the `amount` and `col7` column should be brought from `df_1`. If `amount` is null then 0 should be populated instead

Comment: but amount is not null in your test case. hence, no nulls. *suggesting again, try selecting all columns from both dataframes to visualize the join better.*

Comment: Ideally this should give me null values isn't it because those rows aren't there in `df_1`.

Comment: if you look at the join keys, df2's first row matches with df1's last row, and df2's second row matches df1's first & second rows.

Comment: In that case other than joining on the amount column there is no other way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all rows returned, use an outer join. With a left join, any rows in df1 that don't join to df2 are thrown away. With an outer join, all rows from both dataframes are kept. With an outer join, you need to decide whether to give df1['amount'] or df2['amount'] priority in your coalesce, or lit(0) if neither are available.

Maybe you're looking for a union with a dropDuplicates?

Comment: *"With a left join, any rows in df2 that don't join to df1 are thrown away."* - this seems incorrect given OP is doing `df2.join(df1,...,...)`

Comment: @user2704177 - My use case wouldn't be solved using a `union`.